# Sequelize findAndCountAll rows not in associations

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

There are two tables: `Books`, listing available books, and `BorrowedBooks`, listing books that are currently borrowed. I want to retrieve only books that are currently available (not borrowed), providing pagination and total number count.

I would use the method [`findAndCountAll`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAndCount) provided by Sequelize, which is really easy to use and does most of the works, but it does not work properly. I have tried the following piece of code, using the [`findAll`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll) method, which works correctly.

```
Books.findAll({
    where: { '$BorrowedBooks.bookId$': null },
    include: [BorrowedBooks]
}).then(...).catch(...);
```

Then I changed the method to `findAndCountAll`, in order to obtain the total count of elements and also providing pagination.

```
Books.findAndCountAll({
    where: { '$BorrowedBooks.bookId$': null },
    include: [BorrowedBooks],
    offset: offset,
    limit: limit,
    distinct: true
}).then(...).catch(...);
```

This version produces an error `Unknown column 'BorrowedBooks.bookId' in 'where clause'`.

**EDIT**

The generated query with the piece of code that does not work is the following:

```
SELECT 
    `books`.*,
    `borrowedBooks`.`bookId` AS `borrowedBooks.bookId`,
    `borrowedBooks`.`userId` AS `borrowedBooks.userId`,
FROM
    (SELECT 
        `books`.`id`,
        `books`.`title`,
        `books`.`author`,
        `books`.`isbn`
    FROM
        `books` AS books`
    WHERE
        (SELECT 
                `bookId`
            FROM
                `borrowedBooks`
            WHERE
                (`borrowedBooks`.`bookId` = `books`.`id`
                    AND `borrowedBooks`.`bookId` IS NULL)
            LIMIT 1) IS NOT NULL
    LIMIT 0 , 10) AS `books`
        INNER JOIN
    `borrowedBooks` ON `books`.`id` = `borrowedBooks`.`bookId`
        AND `borrowedBooks`.`bookId` IS NULL;
```

If I would write down directly the query I would do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `books`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `borrowedBooks` ON `books`.`id` = `borrowedBooks`.`bookId`
WHERE `borrowedBooks`.`bookId` IS NULL
```

I think that the error is due to the INNER JOIN that Sequelize uses.

Answer (score 4):

Correct syntax to use include

```
Books.findAll({
    include: [{
      model: BorrowedBooks,
      where: {
        bookId: null
      }
    }],
    offset: offset,
    limit: limit,
    distinct: true
}).then(...).catch(...);
```

Comment: I tested this version and returned me an emtpy list, but there are rows in Book table that are not referenced in the BorrowedBook table.

Comment: No errors are generated, but it is not the desired output. I'll add the query generated and the one I'd use if I won't rely on Sequelize.

Comment: If bookId is the foreign key then it can never be a null value... so how could you use bookId as null in where clause

Comment: If I perform a LEFT JOIN, bookId will be NULL for every row in books that is not referenced in borrowedBooks. As I was saying in the quesion, I think that the problem is related to the INNER JOIN clause used by Sequelize. When using it, rows with bookId NULL are not retrieved.

Comment: @oniramarf show the model and association part also

Answer (score 1):

**Node pagination with sequelize** 
client needs to provide page and pageSize  
`Pass distinct: true` into the query and it will work how you want it to. you will have included data as well.
    `const page = 1
     const pageSize = 2
     const offset = page * pageSize
     const limit = offset + pageSize
     return model
                .findAll({
                    attributes: [],
                    include: [{}],
                    distinct: true,
                    limit,
                    offset
          })
            .then((tasks) => res.status(200).send(tasks))
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                res.status(400).send(error);
            });`